# My Cart Label Value is not increasing in masterpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

MasterPage Code:

```
 public Label OnlbCartCountMasterPage {
        get { return this.chartlabel; }
    }
```

Index.aspx Code

```
String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
string cartQuantity;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadList();
    }

    if (Session["addtocart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cartQuantity = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows.Count);

    }
    else
    {

        cartQuantity = "0";
    }
    Master.OnlbCartCountMasterPage.Text = cartQuantity;
}
```

Add2cart Method:

```
private void add2cart(int id,string lblname,int lblPrice, int lbltotal, int quantitylist, string image) 
{

    if (Session["addtocart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["addtocart"];
        var dataRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == id);
        if (dataRow.Count() == 0)
        {
            //lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = id;
            dr["Item"] = lblname;
            dr["Price"] = lblPrice;
            dr["quantity"] = quantitylist;
            dr["total"] = lbltotal;
            dr["image"] = image;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["addtocart"] = dt;
            cartQuantity= dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            Master.OnlbCartCountMasterPage.Text = cartQuantity;
        }
        else
        {
            //lblErrorMessage.Text = "Item Already Added!";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("total", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("image", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ID"] = id;
        dr["Item"] = lblname;
        dr["Price"] = lblPrice;
        dr["quantity"] = quantitylist;
        dr["total"] = lbltotal;
        dr["image"] = image;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Session["addtocart"] = dt;
        cartQuantity=Convert.ToString(dt.Rows.Count);
    }
    Master.OnlbCartCountMasterPage.Text = cartQuantity;
}
```

Button Code

```
protected void btnAddtoCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField hfid = item.FindControl("hfId") as HiddenField;
    Label lblitem= item.FindControl("item") as Label;
    Label lblPrice = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
    DropDownList lblQuantity = item.FindControl("qtydrpdwn") as DropDownList;
    Label lblTotal = item.FindControl("Total") as Label;
    HiddenField hfimg = item.FindControl("imgpath") as HiddenField;

    add2cart(Convert.ToInt32(hfid.Value),lblitem.Text, Convert.ToInt32(lblPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblTotal.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblQuantity.Text),hfimg.Value);
    btn.Enabled = false;

    //Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
}
```

The problem is occuring in pageload i think? because session is not recognizing the value coming from add2cart method. it is showing the value in the session of add to cart but not in page load. i cant finding out the problem in the code?

And when i click the button to add to cart. the value remains same 0 not increasing at all?

Comment: where do you call `add2cart(...)` ?

Comment: add2cart(Convert.ToInt32(hfid.Value),lblitem.Text, Convert.ToInt32(lblPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblTotal.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblQuantity.Text),hfimg.Value);

Comment: just for clarification: you press the button -> it executes `add2cart` -> which writes something into `Session` -> and then you check in `Page_Load`whether something is in `Session` , but the condition `Session["addtocart"] != null` remains false. did I get it right?

Comment: I suppose `Session` is a class variable situated in the same class as `add2Cart` and `Page_Load`. What is `Session` and what happens with it in the meanwhile between button press and the call of `Page_Load`?

Comment: i am not getting your point sir?

Comment: You write : "it is showing the value in the session of add to cart but not in page load" apparently something happens to Session. From your code it is not apparent at which point in time `Page_Load` is fired. Might it be that `Session` is reinitialized with `new` at certain point between button press and the firing of the `Page_Load`event?

Comment: thanx i solved the problem sir :)

Comment: glad to hear. It would make the post here more valuable if you would also post your solution so that other people could profit from it. I would do it, but I don't know what you did :)

Comment: yes sir but one more problem occur which is when i am refreshing the page only then cart value change not at the time of click? can u help me?

Comment: it would be good to know under which circumstances the `Page_Load`event ist fired in your code. Certainly when your page is loaded this code is executed, may be you should put this update routine in your button press event. It would also be helpful is you would post the button press code

Comment: can you send me the code please. i am editing my question with button trigger event,

Comment: it is working well when i am using response.redirect()  it refresh the page and i dont want to refresh the full page.but without it, the code isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I outsourced the update routine in a seperate method which is called each time the button is pressed.

```
String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
string cartQuantity;

// this will be executed when the page is loaded at the beginning or when refreshed
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I don't know what this does, if you also need it for the update
    // then put it into the updateQuantity method
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadList();
    }

    // update quantity
    updateQuantity();
}

// method to update the quantity
private void updateQuantity()
{
    if (Session["addtocart"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cartQuantity = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        cartQuantity = "0";
    }
    Master.OnlbCartCountMasterPage.Text = cartQuantity;
}


protected void btnAddtoCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    HiddenField hfid = item.FindControl("hfId") as HiddenField;
    Label lblitem= item.FindControl("item") as Label;
    Label lblPrice = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
    DropDownList lblQuantity = item.FindControl("qtydrpdwn") as DropDownList;
    Label lblTotal = item.FindControl("Total") as Label;
    HiddenField hfimg = item.FindControl("imgpath") as HiddenField;

    add2cart(Convert.ToInt32(hfid.Value),lblitem.Text, Convert.ToInt32(lblPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblTotal.Text), Convert.ToInt32(lblQuantity.Text),hfimg.Value);
    btn.Enabled = false;

    //call update method
    updateQuantity();
}
```